# Xcode 5 using a button to switch view controllers

Tags: cocoa-touch

Ok I'm new to iOS development and i just want to press my button "LogIn" and if my textfield is null send an UIAlertView.  If its not null then navigate to the view controller "TimeClockView" but its not navigating to TimeClockView.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TimeClockView.h"

………………

- (void)LogIn:(id)sender
{
    if ([nameTextField.text  isEqual: @""])
    {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"What's The Issue?"
                                                          message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Your Name"]    
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [message show];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeClockView *temp = [[TimeClockView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES]; 

        name = nameTextField.text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be an action to perform a segue. 
So i created another button create a segue with it.
Then use if statement in my original button (IBAction)
to go the other view controller

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `temp` object with a nil nib name. That parameter is needed to know which ViewController (with corresponding nib) you want to instantiate. If you're using nibs to construct your ViewControllers, then change your instantiating code to something like this:

```
TimeClockView *temp = [[TimeClockView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
```

With "YourNibName" being whatever your nib file is named.

However, if you're using Storyboards, then there's an entirely different way of presenting other ViewControllers. You'll need to research performing segues with storyboard.

Also, you'll want to use the `isEqualToString:` method when comparing strings. So rewrite your if/else statement like this:

```
if ([nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //do stuff
}
else {
    //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm still having a problem navigating to my second view controller in my else statement.

Comment: Okay sorry I thought that might fix your navigation. I see the issue. Are you using storyboards?

Comment: So you figured it out?

Comment: No but at least I least I know I need to be researching segues